# Take the max from a SUM

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to combine three tables to determine the richest person en to see who has less than half of that money.

The 3 tables are:

```
Persons (id, name)

BankAccounts(id,balance)

AccountOf(id,person_id → Persons,account_id → BankAccounts)
```

Where id is unique in every table

The question is:
Write a query that returns the names of all people that have less than half of the wealth of the richest person. We define the wealth of a person as the total money on all of his/her accounts.

I'm stuck here. I got this so far:

```
SELECT P1.name, SUM(B.balance) as b
FROM Persons P1
LEFT JOIN AccountOf A1
ON A1.person_id = P1.id
LEFT JOIN BankAccounts B
ON B.id = A1.account_id
GROUP BY name
```

Which gives every name and the sum of their balance over all their accounts. But after that I cannot use WHERE to determine where

```
SUM(b) < 0.5 * MAX(b)
```

The one with no accounts at all needs to be counted as a poor person as well. And I only want to make a table of the names without their balances behind it.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT P1.name, SUM(B.balance) as b
FROM Persons P1
LEFT JOIN AccountOf A1 ON A1.person_id = P1.id
LEFT JOIN BankAccounts B ON B.id = A1.account_id
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(B.balance) < MAX((SELECT SUM(B.balance) as b
  FROM AccountOf A1
  LEFT JOIN BankAccounts B ON B.id = A1.account_id
  GROUP BY A1.person_id ORDER BY b DESC  LIMIT 1)
) * 0.5
```

Comment: Yeah, this was almost it. Needed the name of the person without a account as well, but found that myself after your post! Thanks!